Point-like defects in topological phases
In topologically ordered phases of matter, point-like defects can have some peculiar properties compared to higher-dimensional defects (such as boundaries or domain walls). For one thing, it is known that only bosons can be fused into vacuum at a boundary. For example, the toric code model shown below (picture taken from Kitaev-Kong'12) has two different types of gapped boundaries, one is called a smooth boundary, where one can fuse a magnetic vortex $m$ into vacuum, and the other is called a rough boundary, where one can fuse an electric charge $e$ into vacuum. Both $e$ and $m$ are bosons. However, it is possible to fuse a fermion $\psi=e\times m$ into vacuum at the intersection point (the upper-left corner) between these two different types of boundaries, which is a point-like defect (a defect of codimension 2).

My question concerns the generality of this phenomenon:

Given a 2D quantum double phase described by a Drinfeld center $Z(\mathcal{C})$ (where $\mathcal{C}$ is a unitary fusion category), which type of topological excitations (anyons) can be fused into vacuum at a point-like defect?

We call a point-like defect  a black defect if every type of topological excitation in this topological phase can be fused into vacuum at this point. For example, the upper-left corner in the toric code model shown above is a black defect.  In which family of topological phases does there exist a black defect?


I'm primarily focused on 2D topological order, but I'm interested in the  generalization to 3D case as well.
